NetCore Docker deployment
I have question about NetCore and Angular/React Front app inside EC2 Linux.
We want to use docker for NetCore app and deploy it in EC2 Linux, and use Nginx to hold the frontend Angular/React app.
Because frontend is under Nginx, but the NetCore docker app is communicating inside EC2 wihout Nginx, is this docker app production ready? Otherwise, do we need to deploy NetCore Dcoker app under Nginx or IIS?
If this is not production ready, is there any other alternative good choice?

There is nothing intrinsically not production ready about installing apps directly on EC2 instances.
Personally, I would add docker support to the netcore app and then deploy using something like ECS.

Thank you very much! My concern is that build .net ocre in docker is using Kestrel, not the IIS or Nginx, for sure, we will have frontend app deploy using Nginx also behind AWS Load Balancer, but we are running docker .net core container image inside EC2 linux, is Kestrel production ready? I'm wondering Kestrel and docker can handle production traffic and it is stable.

In production systems as higher traffic volumes need to be catered for you would use CloudFront or other CDNs to cache and distribute static content. Kestrel is consequently an acceptable choice even in the most demanding production environments.
